# Automating the creation of name badges for an event

Tags: templates, automation

We are organizing an event. There will be around 60 participants and I need to prepare name badges (tags) for them.

The badge will involve, `name surname` and `affiliation` fields which is different for each participant.

These fields are already in an Excel sheet actually. So, I can easily export them to a csv file.

And there will be a footer with a logo (picture) and the name of the organization.

I want to create a PDF holding 8 or 10 cards per page and then cut with scissors.

I can create the file manually in Word but I don't like to. How can I automate this process in LaTeX?

As an example, here's a simple design that I would like to have:

[image]

Comment: I use `datatool.sty` to this.

Comment: I have seen a solution with a Visual Basic macro in Excel that generated the namecards on new worksheets.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`ticket`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ticket/doc) package fits very well for this use. The pin example is what you seek for:

```
%%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for a pin for conferences
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[freepin,crossmark]{ticket}

% load misc stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
  \put(50,  3){\includegraphics[width=15mm]{ifmlogoc}}
  \put( 5, 13){\line(1,0){60}}
  \put( 7, 10){\scriptsize Animal annual meeting (AAM)}
  \put( 7,  7){\scriptsize In the gardens}
  \put( 7,  4){\scriptsize April 1, 2000}
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\confpin}[2]{\ticket{%
    \put(35,36){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries\Large #1}}
    \put(35,28){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries\large #2}}%
}}


%% the pins for the partipiciants ... ;-)
%% you can generate this part from a database!
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\confpin{Camelus dromedarius}{North Africa}
\confpin{Urocyon cinereoargenteus}{America}
\confpin{Galago moholi}{South Africa}
\confpin{Dasypus novemcintus}{South America}
\confpin{Rhinocerus sondaicus}{Java}
\confpin{Canis lupus}{Northern sphere}
\confpin{Ramphastus spec.}{South Amerika}
\confpin{Panthera tigris sondaica}{Java}
\confpin{Hippocampus spec.}{the ocean}
\confpin{Anthonomus grandis}{Mexico}
\confpin{Petrogale penicillata}{Australia}
\confpin{Tarsius spec.}{Sumatra}
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

For boxed badges, use

```
\usepackage[freepin,boxed]{ticket}
```

in the preamble. For the other options, see the [manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/ticket/doc/manual.pdf).

To create `confpin` content, you can use the following command in Excel and copy the content to your document. It assumes that column A has `name surname`, and column B has `affiliation`.

```
=CONCATENATE("\confpin{"; A2; "}{";B2; "}")
```

Comment: I met this package while looking for a solution and really liked it. So, I decided to put it here as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple example. Please, adapt it to your case.

**The file `informations.csv`** (the first line is for variable names)

```
"name","sirname","university"
"Aaaa","Bbbb","Cccc"
```

**The file `foo.tex`** (format according to your preferences)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% If the error
% ``No room for ..''
% increase the reserved inserts
%--------------------------------------------
% \usepackage{etex} % to use etex extensions 
% \reserveinserts{28} % using etex extensions

\usepackage[english]{babel}

% UTF-8 support any characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ucs}
% Defaul loaded character table is ASCII and latin

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % amsfonts is part of amssymb

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
%\usepackage{chancery} % change serif to Zapf Chancery
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.6cm,rmargin=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox} % border page and boxes
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\sloppy

\pagestyle{empty}

% box around pages, using fancybox package
%
% \fancypage{\fbox}{}
% \fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\setlength{\shadowsize}{8pt}\shadowbox}{}


%\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\shadowbox}{}
\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\doublebox}{}

\newcommand{\event}{Insert the title of event here}

\begin{document}
% default separator is coma and default delimiter is double quote      
% \DTLsetseparator{,}
% \DTLsetdelimiter{"}

\DTLloaddb{list}{informations.csv}

\DTLforeach{list}{%
\firstname=name,\sirname=sirname,\university=university}{%

\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont  
\baselineskip 2.5em

\vspace*{2cm} 

\begin{center}
{\Large \firstname~\MakeUppercase{\sirname}}

\vskip 2cm 

{\large \university}

\vfill 

\hrulefill

\event~\fbox{logo here}
\end{center}

\newpage
}  
\end{document}
```

**The output**
[image]

Comment: I created a file with the content wou gave but I got many errors: `Missing \endcsname inserted:    \DTLloaddb{list}{informations.csv}"`, `Missing { inserted:    \DTLloaddb{list}{informations.csv}`, `Package datatool Error: Can't assign \firstname : there is no key `name' in data base `list':    }`.

Comment: And actually I would like to get many badges in an A4 page. Not getting a badge per page.

Comment: I believe that the easiest way is to print more than one page, changing the printer options. My sample create one page for each line on `csv` file. You can change the page size using `geometry` (see the code) and then you print 4 or 8 pages per sheet.

Comment: Your `csv` file looks like mine? Does it have the same variables defined? Did you save it on the same folder as your `tex` file?

Comment: Yes, I've created it in the same folder with the same name and content.

Comment: And I forgot the first error actually. It says: `Undefined control sequence:    \GenericError  ...                                :    \DTLloaddb{list}{informations.csv}`

Comment: Strange, everything is fine for me. Please, check if the `datatool` package was loaded on the `log` file.

Answer (score 7):

A slight variation from Sigur's answer, building on his code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{informations.csv}
name,sirname,university
Jon,Doe,From Moon
Jane,Dipp,From Mars
Jon,Doe,From Moon
Jane,Dipp,From Mars
Jon,Doe,From Moon
Jane,Dipp,From Mars
Jon,Doe,From Moon
Jane,Dipp,From Mars
Jon,Doe,From Moon
Jane,Dipp,From Mars
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{cards.tex}
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[lmargin=1cm,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.6cm,rmargin=1.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox} % border page and boxes
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\sloppy
\pagestyle{empty}
\fancypage{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\doublebox}{}
\newcommand{\event}{Univeristy Name \\
University Address - 1\\
University Address - 2}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{list}{informations.csv}

\DTLforeach{list}{%
\firstname=name,\sirname=sirname,\university=university}{%
\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont  
\baselineskip 2.5em
\vspace*{2cm} 
\begin{center}
{\Large \firstname~\MakeUppercase{\sirname}}
\vskip 2cm 
{\large \university}
\vfill 

\hrulefill

\parbox[b]{.7\textwidth}{\event}\hfill\fbox{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{center}
\newpage
}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
% compile with pdflatex
\immediate\write18{pdflatex cards.tex}
%
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x4,delta=0.0in 0cm,turn=true,frame=true]{cards.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, how to use your code? Should I save it on a `tex` file? What to do with `\immediate\write18{pdflatex cards.tex}`?

Comment: @Sigur Just save the code as `somefile.tex` and `pdflatex somefile.tex`.

Comment: I got `! Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `cards.pdf'.`

Comment: @Sigur cards.pdf will be created in the same folder (unless you have some mechanism to move it elsewhere) as the `somefile.tex`. Just look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't note the `\inclugraphics`. I have to change it.

Comment: Irrelevant here, but 'Information' is plural, and 'informations' is wrong. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple solution using `pstricks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}%..% to create card and position tags/labels
\usepackage{graphicx}%..% for loading and working with the logo
\usepackage{datatool}%..% for managing source for names and affiliations
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%% command to handle the event name and related matter.
\newcommand{\eventname}{\begin{minipage}[c]{2.5in}\raggedright{}%
                            Name of Event \\ 
                            Sponsored by Various and Sundry
                        \end{minipage}}
%% in case you want some white space for when cutting the cards:  otherwise set both to zero.
\newlength{\cardhsep}\setlength{\cardhsep}{2pt}%..% horizontal space between cards
\newlength{\cardvsep}\setlength{\cardvsep}{2pt}%..% vertical space between rows of cards
\newcounter{cntnamecard}                       %..% counter to keep track of namecard and facilitate making "paragraphs"
\psset{unit=0.25in}                            %..% or you can set "xunit=..." and "yunit=..." change dimensions of card
\newcommand{\namecard}[3]{%
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(14,8)
        \rput(7,6){\Large{}\textbf{\sffamily{}#1}}%..% node for name
        \rput(7,5){#2}                            %..% node for affiliation
        \psline(0.25,1.75)(13.75,1.75)
        \rput[l](0.25,1){#3}                      %..% node for event name
        \rput[r](13.75,1){\includegraphics[height=0.33in]{example-image-a}}%..% logo
        \pspolygon(0,0)(14,0)(14,8)(0,8)
    \end{pspicture}\hspace*{\cardhsep}%
    \ifodd\thecntnamecard\par\fi%..% automate when "paragraphs" are set.
    \stepcounter{cntnamecard}}
%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%..% no need for indentation.
\setlength{\parskip}{\dimexpr-\lineskip+\cardvsep\relax}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{namecard}{data.csv}
\DTLforeach{namecard}{\firstname=first,
                      \lastname=last,
                      \school=affiliation,
                      \characterization=characterization}
    {\namecard{\firstname{} \lastname}
              {\school}
              {\eventname}}

\end{document}
```

where the `cvs` file looks something like:

```
"first","last","affiliation","characterization"
  "Bilbo","Baggins","Hobbit U.","Lover of Adventure"
  "Charles","Dickens","Victorian U.","Serial Author"
  "Galileo","Galilei","U. of Pisa","Science Guru"
  "Bruce","Wayne","University of Gotham","Comic Hero"
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have some empty spaces around the borders, to help cutting it.

Answer (score 1):

(For completeness)

The [labels package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/labels) is initially designed for generating printed labels on sticker paper for snail mail. It can print those types of badges, but with probably less personalization than the *ticket* package mentionned in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94600/11083) (for example, I'm not sure you can add graphics).

Usage: you define your card size (number of rows, columns, margins,etc.), then give as input the file where all your names are stored, and it generates a pdf file holding the badges.

The manual is pretty clear, but it seems that the package hasn't been updated for quite a long time.

Sample (taken from the manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{labels}
\begin{document}
\labelfile{names.dat}
\end{document}
```