# How to change ticketsize with ticket.sty?

Tags: labels, templates

I can't seem to change the ticketsize in LaTeX.

```
%%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for a pin for conferences
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
%\hoffset=-16.2mm
%\voffset=-6.6mm

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[freepin,crossmark]{ticket}
\unitlength=1mm
\ticketSize{77}{45}
```

I tried a few different positions of the \ticketSize{77}{45) option.
I found this package here: [Automating the creation of name badges for an event](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94582/automating-the-creation-of-name-badges-for-an-event/94600#94600).
Any help woulb much appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: Well, the package seems to have too many parameters which are user-configurable.  E.g. if you change the ticket size to `\ticketSize{97}{65}` you must also correspondingly increase the line dimensions with `\put( 5, 13){\line(1,0){90}}` and maybe the logo also to `\put(80,  3){\includegraphics[..]{...}` to fit everything nicely.  If you give a better idea of what you want (a picture, maybe) I could try to achieve that by playing with the dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ticket` package seems to have too many parameters which are user-configurable. E.g. if you change the ticket size with `\ticketSize{97}{65}` you must also correspondingly increase the line dimensions with `\put( 5, 13){\line(1,0){90}}` and maybe the logo also to `\put(80, 3){\includegraphics[..]{...}` to fit everything nicely. Here's something I did to scale up the whole picture:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[freepin,crossmark]{ticket}


\unitlength=1mm
\ticketSize{97}{65}

% load misc stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
\put(80,  3){\includegraphics[width=14mm]{ifmlogoc}}
\put( 5, 13){\line(1,0){90}}
\put( 7,  9){\footnotesize Annual General Meeting (AGM)}
\put( 7,  6){\footnotesize Eden Gardens, Kolkata}
\put( 7,  3){\footnotesize January 21, 2019}
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\confpin}[2]{\ticket{%
    \put(49,42){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries\LARGE #1}}
    \put(49,32){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries\Large #2}}%
}}


%% the pins for the partipiciants ... ;-)
%% you can generate this part from a database!
\begin{document}
 \sffamily
  \confpin{Ritwik Ghatak}{India}
  \confpin{Ingmar Bergman}{Sweden}
\end{document}
```

which generates the **output:**

[image]

in contrast to the output from [original settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94582/automating-the-creation-of-name-badges-for-an-event/94600#94600) with both paper sizes to `a5paper` for easy comparison:

[image]